# Why doesn't lock! stop others from updating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, locking, mariadb

This is my class:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  def testing
    self.with_lock do
      update_columns(lock: true)
      byebug
    end
  end

  def testing2
    self.lock!
    byebug
  end
end
```

I opened two rails consoles.

In first console:

```
p = Plan.create
=> (basically success)
p.id
=> 12
p.testing2
(byebug) # simulation of halting the execution,
(BYEBUG) # I just leave the rails console open and wait at here. I expect others won't be able to update p because I still got the lock.
```

On second console:

```
p = Plan.find(12)
=> (basically said found)
p.name = 'should not be able to be stored in database'
=> "should not be able to be stored in database"
p.save!
=> true # what????? Why can it update my object? It's lock in the other console!
```

`lock!` in `testing2` doesn't lock while `with_lock` in testing does work. Can anybody explain why `lock!` doesn't work?

Comment: What is `lock!`?

Comment: @tadman `lock!` is https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html#method-i-lock-21

Comment: Are you asking “why can two separate processes ignore each others’ locks?” Because they’re separate processes.

Comment: @anothermh this should acquire database locks, not application level

Comment: Hi @anothermh, yes, I expect the lock to prevent other process from updating the things I'm locking, in other words, I expect the same thing Oshanz said.

Comment: That makes sense, but you'll need to inherit from that class. Your code was misleading.

Comment: @tadman Good point, I have added ` < ActiveRecord::Base` to the code

Comment: What is your data storage engine?

Comment: @Oshanz this question has a MariaDB tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#lock!` uses SELECT … FOR UPDATE to acquire a lock.
According to [PostgreSQL doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS).

> FOR UPDATE causes the rows retrieved by the SELECT statement to be locked as though for update. This prevents them from being locked, modified or deleted by other transactions until the current transaction ends.

You need a transaction to keep holding a lock of a certain row.

Try
console1:

```
Plan.transaction{Plan.find(12).lock!; sleep 100.days}
```

console2:

```
p = Plan.find(12)
p.name = 'should not be able to be stored in database'
p.save
```

`#with_lock` acquire a transaction for you, so you don't need explicit transaction.

(This is PostgreSQL document. But I think other databases implement similar logic.  )

Comment: Brilliant, after surround it with `Plan.transaction` block, the code behave as I expect.

Comment: By the way, in console2, are you sure it will raise an exception? I'm using MariaDB and it just halt there (and continue execution when my byebug block session finishes).

Comment: I tried this using sqlite and had an exception.  But an exception not always raise. It depends on your database and configurations.

Comment: I fixed my answer. (Deleted `# => Exception`)